# Laravel 8 GroupBy Is returning me the First records only for each group but i need All the Recors in a group by manner

Tags: php, laravel, join, group-by

I have 3 Models **User** , **MyClass** And **AssignedClassModels**

**Users Table**

| id | forename | lastname |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Rayhan | Parvez |  |
| 2 | Tuhin | Saud |  |
| 3 | Asif | Ahmed |  |
| 4 | Shuvo | Khan |  |

**MyClasses table**

| id | name |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ten |  |
| 2 | Six |  |

**AssignedClassModels Table**

| id | MyClass_id | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 4 |

So, now I want to join these 3 table and want to get the result in a group by class manner but it always give me the first records of each group.

**This is my Output Result in JSON**

```
{
success: true,
message: "Display All The Pupil list Group by Class",
data: [

    {
    id: 1,
    forename: "Rayhan",
    lastname: "Parvez",
    class_name: "Ten",
    class_id: 1
    },
    {
    id: 2,
    forename: "Tuhin",
    lastname: "Saud",
    class_name: "Six",
    class_id: 2
    }

]
}
```

***Here is my Controller Code***

**AssignedClassController**

```
public function index()
    {
        try {
            $class_list = DB::table('assigned_class_models')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'assigned_class_models.user_id')
            ->join('my_classes', 'my_classes.id', '=', 'assigned_class_models.MyClass_id')
            ->select('users.id','users.forename','users.lastname','my_classes.name as class_name','my_classes.id as class_id')
            ->groupBy('my_classes.id')
            ->get();
             
            
            return response()->json([
                'success'=> true,
                'message' => 'Display All The user list Group by Class',
                'data'  => $class_list

            ] , 200);
        } 
        catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return response()->json([
                'success'=> false,
                'message' => 'Unauthorized User',
            ] , 401);
        }
       
    }
```

***Here is my Model Code***

**AssignedClassModel**

```
class AssignedClassModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function User(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class , 'user_id' , 'id');
    }

    public function MyClass(){
        return $this->belongsTo(MyClass::class , 'MyClass_id' , 'id');
    }
}
```

But It is not giving me the All records of Each group but instead of giving this it is giving me the first record of each group why?

Comment: you have to use eloquent and laravel relations then its very easy to use

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships  you have to follow this  if need more help then tell me

Comment: Can you help me @RakeshkumarOad in eloquent relationship

Comment: yes you have to update your question add you models also then i can help you

Comment: @RakeshkumarOad  
**$class_list =AssignedClassModel::With(['User','MyClass'])->groupBy('MyClass_id')->get();**

i tried also with this eloquent but giving me the same output

Comment: yes use it eloquent .

Comment: update your question add models then i will help you proper

Comment: @RakeshkumarOad Question is updated With Model.

Comment: groupBy replace with orderBy    then you will get your acurate result .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***By using the Eloquent Model We can fix It Easily Here is the Solve Bellow:***

**Use these code in model AssignedClassModel**

```
class AssignedClassModel extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function User(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class , 'user_id' , 'id');
    }

    public function MyClass(){
        return $this->belongsTo(MyClass::class , 'MyClass_id' , 'id');
    }
}
```

**Use These Code in Controller**

```
$list =AssignedClassModel::With(['User','MyClass'])->get();
$list2 = $list->groupBy('MyClass_id');

return response()->json([
                'success'=> true,
                'message' => 'All The User list Group by Class',
                'data'  => $list2

            ] , 200);
```

***Now You Will get the Perfect Output.***

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `groupBy` into `orderBy`

then you will get your accurate result

Note: groupBy Skip the same values so you are getting the result of first rows .

I hope you got your solution thanks .

Comment: Sorry but orderBy() is giving me all the records but I need class wise groupBy() Records